# A product with multiple variations, but not grouped product

Tags: grouped-products

I need to show a product with multiple variations, but not to be sell as a grouped product.
The variations must be sell individually.
To understand, i need to copy this configuration:

https://www.mobiltecnica.com/it/punte-ad-attacco-rapido-per-foratrici-in-hw-micrograna_3_1

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a configurable product?

These can give you the option to choose a variation of the product. For example you could have a t-shirt that's has different colours and sizes, the user can choose any combination:

Sizes

- S
- M
- L

Colours

- Red
- Blue
- Green

See the configurable product guide here - http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable.html

Comment: Yes, but i need multiple configurable products in one single product page.
I think i'll need to create a grouped product and customize the template